# Why do accelerating anodes work?

Tags: oscilloscope

Once the electrons pass through them, won’t they be decelerated again? I think it might have two reasons.

First, that the fluorescent screen is itself at a quite high potential. But that would cause the electrons to not move in a straight line after they pass through the deflection plates. However, in deriving deflection sensitivity (and other theory), we assume that the electrons move in a straight line after they pass through the plates. Also, if the screen is not an anode, where do the electron go after striking the screen?

Second, the velocity of electrons after coming through the accelerating anode is so high that they need a large distance to travel before sufficient deceleration. And the field due to screen is feeble as compared to the final electron speeds.

Please correct.

Comment: The field gradients are significantly affected by the closeness of the grouped electrodes.  Many scopes have additional acceleration after the last gun anode but I have not heard of one having deceleration by design.

Answer (score 1):

After leaving the electron gun, electrons are in an electric-field-free space...in every direction they see high voltage equal to the voltage of the electron gun's final anode. So they travel in a straight line, constant velocity.
Until they hit the phosphor screen.

After that, they are collected by the conducting **aquadag** coating, which is also at the same high-voltage of the final anode. From there, they return (as beam current) to the high-voltage DC supply. Some glass may have no aquadag - then electrons find their way to the final anode.

A test setup had one of these old tubes run with a variable +high-voltage anode supply. At low accelerating voltage, electrons sometimes would "stick" to the phosphor when they hit. Perhaps a section of phosphor that was electrically isolated - it is a thin coating. That section became charged, and the electron beam would not go there - it became dark and wouldn't glow.
 If anode voltage was raised, the higher-speed electrons would un-charge that spot, and instantly, it would light up as it should. This dark-region-thing would only happen when the accelerating voltage was much lower than the intended operating voltage.

Comment: *”If anode voltage was raised, the higher-speed electrons would un-charge that spot...”* How?

Comment: @Atom The mechanism of clearing that spot was not investigated. Electrons hitting the C.R.T. face was used in a **Williams tube** early computer memory. Try a Wikipedia search to learn more.

Comment: @glen_geek "In every direction they see high voltage equal to the voltage of the electron gun's final anode." Is that because the configuration (creating an homogeneous field)?

Comment: @Anton From electron gun's anode (buried in the CRT neck) to the CRT face, electrons travel straight line, constant velocity. So there's no electric field at all in that space. Not a homogeneous field.

Comment: @glen_geek I was asking why they don't revert back to the positively charged anode. The homogeneous field I reffered was that of anode-cathode. Apologize if I was not clear enough.

Comment: @Anton After losing momentum by hitting CRT face, electrons *do revert* back to the anode and from there back to the +high-voltage anode supply. Aquadag coating on glass inner surface is connected to +high voltage - that would likely be where bounced electrons go. Every electron that flies out of the electron gun anode ring (in CRT neck) ends up collected by +anode.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks for your answer I will search for the aquadag coating.